# NSDateFormatter not giving proper response while setting date

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a little bit problem.
Please look at here and understand this problem.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    self.datePicker.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    NSString *dateString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

This is my block where I am returning a date. but when I set there `NSLocale` then this will not give me proper response.

I want a **DATE** in `dd-MMM-yyyy` **(24-Mar-2008)** formate. but it is giving response :

**iOS8.0** and Latter --> **24-M03-2004**

**iOS7.0** and Older  --> **24-Month03-2004**

because of some dependency I cant remove `[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];` from my above block.
please suggest me how can I handle this problem,

Comment: [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];   Instead of  
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]; and you will be good to go

Comment: can you share your datepicker.date value?

Comment: @adnan your answer is correct.

Comment: @muku datepicker.date value is coming from NSDatePicker.

Comment: This is hapning because of **[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]** and its only supported respect to new version of iOS. hope you can get some logic because of this info...

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

insteade of

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
```

This will return the format you want.

Answer (score 3):

This will resolve your problem

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

or

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```